# Mac (OS X) v.s. PC (Windows) for Graphic Design

Tags: windows, macos, colors

This is my first post on this site, I've been googling for few months for this answer but none of them are really what I'm looking for.

I've been using Windows since the first time I got my hands on a keyboard (12 years ago, I'm 22), but since I put myself seriously into Graphic Design I found most graphic designer use Mac (so am I, in the office).

When I got few years experiences on a Mac, I found the main advantages of using Mac for Design is the COLOR THAT APPEARS ON THE SCREEN. I insert a specific color code (RED: C:1% M:100% Y:100% K:4%) on both systems, but on Mac the colors appears MORE RED and on Windows the Red seems to be washed out (both have glossy screen). My little brother use Linux on his laptop (the laptop has antiglare screen, AFAIK antiglare screen reduces saturation appears on the screen) when I tried the same thing the RED APPEARS THE SAME as seen on Mac, but the edges are very pixelated (Windows:1366x768 Mac:1280x800 Linux:1366x768).

**MY BIG QUESTION IS:
What's really make the difference here? Is it the *OS* or *The Screen* or *BOTH* ?**

I'm about to make a serious purchase for my workstation (All In One form), if I can get any great answer here I might get a better sleep on the future nights. :D

Comment: If you want accurate colors, you need to calibrate. No exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If the thing you are most concerned about is the fidelity of the hue of the colours you see on your screen, you can use a colorimeter like Spyder to calibrate your display. The calibration data is then stored in your computer's graphic card so it displays consistently on the monitor attached to the card. In this way you can make an image display exactly the same on a Windows PC, Apple laptop or Linux server. All with different monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I think Macs are better in general than PCs are :-)

But personal preferences aside, it's a persistent myth that Macs are 'better' for graphics design work than PCs are.  It was true a long time ago, but that's ancient history.  They're both fine for graphics work.  There are only a couple ticks where Macs may have a slight edge, but they're minor.

- Mac monitors are color-calibrated by default, but that makes no difference if you're using an external (non-Apple) display.  But even so, color calibrators work on Macs and PCs equally.
- Apple has Retina displays, but this isn't really a good argument because they're only available on MacBooks.  Professional graphics artists do not stare at laptop screens all day.  The only way to get that kind of resolution on a Mac Pro is to get a 4K display, which Apple does not make.
- The new Mac Pros have massive GPU capabilities, which is awesome, but that only really benefits 3D animators and video editors, not graphics designers.

So really, the lesson here is that there's isn't really anything that Macs can do that PCs can't.  One is not better than the other.  The Mac vs. PC debate is mostly a religious argument at this point.

IF you're actually interested in spending $3000+ on a computer, then you may want to check out [this article](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/173695-apples-new-overpriced-10000-mac-pro-is-2000-cheaper-than-the-equivalent-windows-pc).  But aside from that scenario, A PC is most likely going to be cheaper.